# Loading whole file from source into HDFS in flume

Tags: flume

How to get source filename as it is from source into HDFS  in flume?

Ex: source file   /usr/sample.txt   hdfs:   /tmp/sample.txt not like flumeevetns.23343.tmp

how to stop appending timestamp and .tmp?Ex:flumeevent.12334343.tmp(Here 12334343.tmp) I dont want it.

How to read as a whole file from Flume?

How to read csv file in Flume?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a parameter for spooldir which adds a header which is false by 
default.

> agentname.sources.sourcename.fileHeader=true

It will keep the same name of file and push into HDFS.